# For loop should not execute

Tags: c++

In this code

```
std::vector<int> vec;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < vec.size() - 1; i++) {

        std::cout << "Print" << std::endl;
    }
```

Though `vec` has no input members so the `for` loop should not execute at all since `i` will be more than the condition for execution which is `vec.size() - 1`.

But still the loop is executing.

Comment: Replace `vec.size() - 1` with `vec.size() `

Comment: Always compile C++ with warnings on (`-Wall` on gcc). It'll tell you about things like this.

Comment: ```vec.size()``` returns an unsigned value 0, which will underflow and rotate to ```std::limits<size_t>::max()``` when you subtract ```1``` from it.  I wonder if you don't get a warning message while compiling that code segment.

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/vectorempty-vectorsize-c-stl/   so suggestion is to typeast `(int)vector.size() - 1`. By the way, shouldn't you be doing `i < vec.size()`?

Comment: @SilvioMayolo It will warn, but at least for GCC and Clang only about the signed/unsigned comparison. Naively replacing `int` with `unsigned` then produces no warning: https://godbolt.org/z/jW6ooYaf5

Comment: @gp. This is a bad way to do it. On 64-bit platforms `vector.size()` could not fit into `int`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`vec.size()` returns an unsigned type. Now `vec.size()` is 0, but `vec.size() - 1` will cause an wrap around, so that's why you see

```
std::cout << "Print" << std::endl;
```

executed